# Jquery/Jscript: Displaying a rotating array of strings from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, keypress

I am trying to write a script that on a keypress event will display one string at a time from an array. Once the array hits the last item in the array it loops back to position 0, thus creating a continuous loop. Right now I have a script that will display each item one at a time, but it does not behave the correct way, nor does it loop back to the beginning.

I do not want it to print each item as a long list, but display the first string on a keypress, and on the next keypress, clears the div and displays the next string in it's place

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rotating Messages</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var i = 0; 
         var messages=["Tonight I\'m gonna have myself a real good time ",
              "I feel alive and the world it\'s turning inside out Yeah! ",
              "I\'m floating around in ecstasy ",
              "So don\'t stop me now don't stop me ",
              "Cause I\'m having a good time having a good time ",
              "I\'m a shooting star leaping through the skies ",
              "Like a tiger defying the laws of gravity ",
              "I\'m a racing car passing by like Lady Godiva ",
              "I'm gonna go go go ",
             "There\'s no stopping me "]


$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {

        if (e.which===13) {
            if(i<=messages.length) { 
                $("#lyrics").append(messages[i]);
                    i=i+1;
            }   
        }
    });
    });




      </script>

    <body>
     <div id="wrapper">
  <header class="title">
   <h1> Fun with Arrays!</h1>
   <div id="lyrics"> </div>

     </body>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/34/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, for a "rotating" array, try this:

```
    if (e.which===13) {

            $("#lyrics").html(messages[++i % messages.length]);
    }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/35/

Comment: Also works and is a cleaner code instead of nesting a third if statement in my function